# How to implement GRU that takes fixed size input tensor and outputs a variable size tensor - in Tensorflow? (Implementation of Kumar et al., 2015)

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

## Detailed explanation

I'm attempting to implement the dynamic memory network described in [Xiong et al. (2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01417.pdf) and [Kumar et al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07285.pdf) for QA tasks. I've made it work for the [bAbi dataset](https://research.fb.com/downloads/babi/) with one-word answers, and get somewhat similar results as the ones described in the papers (and I believe some hyperparameter tuning can close the rest of the gap). This was done using a linear output layer as the answer module. I want to extend the model to produce multi-word answers.

For this my intention has been to use the GRU described in equation 9 and 10 in [Kumar et al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07285.pdf), to decode the output from the episodic memory (m^T in [Kumar et al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07285.pdf) and [Xiong et al (2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01417.pdf)).

This GRU needs to take a 3D tensor of size `[batch_size x 1 x embedding_size]` as input, i.e. the reshaped output from the episodic memory, m^T, and output a 3D tensor of size `[batch_size x answer_length x vocab_size]`.

Thus far I've tried to implement my own GRU to be called by Tensorflow's `dynamic_rnn` method, however I've been unable to do this. In the current state of affairs the call method hereof looks like this:

```py
def call(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
    with vs.variable_scope(scope or "decoder_gru_cell"):
        with vs.variable_scope("gates"):
            z = math_ops.sigmoid(_linear([inputs, state], self._num_units, True))
            r = math_ops.sigmoid(_linear([inputs, state], self._num_units, True))
        with vs.variable_scope("candidate"):
            r = r*_linear(state, self._num_units, False)
        with vs.variable_scope("input"):
            x = _linear(inputs, self._num_units, True)
        h_hat = math_ops.tanh(r + x)
        new_h = z * h_hat + (1 - z) * state
        output = tf.nn.softmax(_linear(new_h))
    return output, new_h
```

I can't seem to make it use the output from time step `t-1` concatenated with the question vector as input for the cell at time step `t`, as described in the papers.

Futhermore, I'm uncertain how I can implement it such that it takes a fixed size input tensor and outputs a variable size tensor (since not all answers necessarily are of the same length). Based on the following sentence from [Xiong et al. (2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01417.pdf), this ought to be possible:

> For tasks requiring a sequence output,
>   an RNN may be used to decode a = [q; m^T], the concatenation of vectors q and m^T, to an ordered set of tokens.

## tl; dr

How do I implement a GRU that takes a fixed size input tensor and outputs a variable size tensor in Tensorflow?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To access the output up to time step t-1 in time step t you must use [TensorArrays](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray) to store the previous activations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I will see if I can make it work.